# I am having trouble getting my text input to append <li> to a blank <ul> in my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My end goal is to have whatever input the user submits append to a blank `ul` of the page. Once the item is appended I'd like the value of the text input to return to a blank text box.  Attempting to create a to-do list pretty much. I am not getting errors on my console so I am not sure what I am doing wrong! Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="list">

    <h1>To Do List</h1>
<form>
<label> Things to Do:
<input id="item" type="text" name="item" placeholder="Items" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add to List"/></label>
</form>
<ul>
</ul>
<button id="clear">Clear List</button>
<button id="completed">Clear Completed Items</button>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//this appends the input inside on an li inside the ul we created in the html
$("form").submit(function(event){
  e.preventDefault();
$("ul").append("<li>" + $("#item")[0].value + "</li>");
$("#item") [0].value="";

});
```

When I attempt this, I notice the value is being saved in the url but not appending to the ul.

Comment: your submit function handler names its' parameter `event`, but you are calling `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: You should be getting an error in your console. Make sure you are looking in the right place. You should be getting "e is not defined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the event of `event` through your form handler, but attempting to prevent the submission with `e`. These two handlers need to have the same name. Simply updating your function to pass through `e` instead of `event` solves this problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this appends the input inside on an li inside the ul we created in the html
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul").append("<li>" + $("#item")[0].value + "</li>");
    $("#item")[0].value = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <form>
    <label> Things to Do:
<input id="item" type="text" name="item" placeholder="Items" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add to List"/></label>
  </form>
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <button id="clear">Clear List</button>
  <button id="completed">Clear Completed Items</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I can't believe that I've spent to much time looking into this for such a small error. It worked for me, thanks so much!!!